# Copying only new entries from a sheet that meet a criteria and adding at the end of a column in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to work through a problem for a sheet I'm working on but my limited vba knowledge has got me stuck.

What I currently have is code that copies over a reference number (column A) for a record to a new sheet if it has the value "CHK" in Column Y. This code is shown below.

The issue i'm having is trying to add some code that means when I run the macro only new entries that match the criteria will be copied over. At the moment when I run the macro it duplicates the entries that have already been copied (i.e. I run the macro once and get 1,2,3 I then run it again, adding another cell, and get 1,2,3,1,2,3,4.

I've been trying to come up with ideas and thought about using "If" to compare the final reference number in the sheet i copy to and the register sheet. And then setting up a similar process that would only copy values that were larger than the final reference number in the sheet i copy to. This would require me to set up the same process as below but limited to only values greater than the final value in the sheet i'm copying to.

This would require two macros i think, one to populate the list the first time (code that is below) and then one to run an update as discussed.

My question was will this process work or are there better ways that i am missing to achieve what I need to achieve.

Thanks all.

```
Sub Copy_detailed_WithNum_V4_Test()

'Create and set worksheet variables
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Detailed Register-All")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("VIPP Register")

'Create search range, cel and lastrow variable 
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, Lastrow As Long

'Set the range to search as column Y in the detailed register (Y2 to last used cell in Y)
Set SrchRng = ws1.Range("Y2:Y" & ws1.Range("Y" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

'Stop screen updating with each action
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cel In SrchRng

    'Check if the VIPP Flag for the entry is CHK
    If InStr(1, cel.Text, "CHK") Then
        'If the entry is CHK, set the lastrow variable as first empty cell in row a of the VIPP Register
        Lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        'Set the value of cells in Column A in VIPP Register to be equal to record number values for those entries that require a VIPP CHK
        ws2.Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value = cel.Offset(0, -24).Value
    End If
'Repeat for next cell in the search range
Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I know this macro ;)

Comment: What column/values determine a duplicate? Is there a unique ID or something of the sorts?

Comment: haha that you do, Each entry to the register has a unique ID (Coulmn A), which is what i'm pulling into the other sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick.

You can run the macros seperately or add `Call RemoveDuplicates` before ending your first sub.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("VIPP Register")
Dim Unique As Range: Set Unique = ws2.Range("A2:A" & ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Dim MyCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range

For Each MyCell In Unique
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws2.Range("A:A"), MyCell) > 1 Then
        If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = MyCell
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, MyCell)
        End If
    End If
Next MyCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

---

This should check to see if your value exists before even pasting which means this one sub should be sufficient.

```
Sub Copy_detailed_WithNum_V4_Test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Detailed Register-All")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("VIPP Register")
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, Lastrow As Long

Set SrchRng = ws1.Range("Y2:Y" & ws1.Range("Y" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cel In SrchRng    
  If InStr(1, cel.Text, "CHK") Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws2.Range("A:A"), cel.Offset(0, -24)) = 0 Then
            Lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            ws2.Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value = cel.Offset(0, -24).Value
        End If
    End If
Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hadn't thought about deleting duplicates rather than only copying new ones. After adding a new record and testing the remove duplicates Macro it removes all entries except for the one new one. I'm left with just 1 unique ID

Comment: Also i understand most of the code. I was wondering if you could explain what the section below does.

If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = MyCell
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, MyCell)
        End If

Comment: I’ll make an edit about explaining the delete me thing

Comment: The second lot of code seems to work successfully. I'm just going to work through and understand the code.